# Filtering a joined list in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, filter

I have two lists, 'A' and 'B'. I need to display their joined data according to certain filters.

A and B are joined using Linked sources and I can filter data by column values from A thanks to this little trick:
http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--design-customization/dataformwebpart-in-sharepoint-designer-linked-to-sql-not-being-able-to-filter-2821.shtml

Does anyone know of any workaround how to filter and sort the displayed form by items from A and B?
For example, can I somehow trick SharePoint into making an SQL query on those two lists or this isn't a job for the SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this scenario should result in a CompositeDataSource in your mark-up.

Inside this each of your lists is defined as a DataSource, in this there is a SELECT which likely just has  (likely that's HTML Encoded too.)

Insert some CAML to Filter and query in to the view.

I recommend using CAML Query Builder to construct this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirements and i achieved it using the jQuery.

I joined the lists using one field so my List B had a field from List A.  In the list A i added a link field that pointed to list B and in Query string i passed the value of the linked field.

In list B i had written a script to parse the query string and show only row that contained the Query String parameter value.

I dont have the script right now but I can surely share it with you.

- Sudhir

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but adding jQuery to the site is not an option.